# RaspberryPi DHT22 temp sensor with ThingSpeak + IFTTT

Tags: python

I have a DHT22 sensor connected to my Pi2, which sends Humidity and Temperature to ThingSpeak channel, everything works nicely. I would like to put this into IFTTT webhook so I may receive notification about humidity or blink hue etc... I have absolutely no idea where to start, if you know any tutorial, or just simply tell me the way, would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague and I have created a comprehensive tutorial for using ThingSpeak, MATLAB, and IFTTT to send notifications. The tutorial is on [Hackster.io](https://www.hackster.io/matlab-iot/thingspeak-matlab-and-ifttt-smart-humidity-sensor-1a8495).

You want to create a MATLAB Analysis script that analyzes your data for a certain condition. They use the MATLAB command `webwrite` to interface to the IFTTT maker webhook. You use ThingSpeak's React app to continuously check if the condition is true with each insert of new data.

```
 webwrite(strcat('https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/', makerEvent, ...
                '/with/key/', makerKey), ...
                'value1', stateMsg, ...
                'value2', char(timeSinceChange, 'HH:mm'));
```